# Case for invertibility of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Take a 4x4 matrix.

Where each column has sum equal 0.

The column space of such a matrix cannot be $\mathbb{R}^4$ since the sum of the entries of every vector on the column space is zero.

Hence, the column rank of the matrix is ≤ 3 and the matrix cannot be invertible.

My questions,

Why does the sum of a column equalling zero result in the column space of a matrix not being in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Is part of the reason that when you attempt to row reduce a matrix of this type to get leading ones in each column and/or no zero rows that this is not possible?

Comment: "*column space of a matrix not being in $\Bbb R^4$*"  You either misspoke or misunderstood.  The column space will certainly be a subspace of $\Bbb R^4$.  "*Why does the sum of* **a** *column equalling zero*"  Again, misspoken or misunderstood. 
 It is that *every* column has sum equal to zero.  What is being said here is that it will be a *proper* subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ and will necessarily be missing certain elements.  "*Is part of the reason that when you attempt to row reduce...*"  Yes, when row reducing you will necessarily find a row of all zeroes here.

Comment: An easier way of seeing this is with the rank-nullity theorem and noting that $[1~1~1~1]A = [0~0~0~0]$ and so $[1~1~1~1]$ is necessarily in the left-nullspace of the matrix and so its left-nullspace is necessarily non-empty and dimension $1$ or greater, making the rowspace dimension 3 or less and thus the rank 3 or less.

Comment: Another way of thinking of this, noting that $Ax$ will necessarily be some linear combination of the columns, it follows that the column vector $Ax$ will necessarily also have the property that its entries sum to zero.  In particular, $Ax$ can never equal something which does not have its entries sum to zero such as $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ showing that the columnspace is incomplete.

Comment: How can I understand that   can never equal something which does not have its entries sum to zero, I have tried vectors and know this to be the case but what is the intuition behind it? What is meant by an incomplete column space?

Comment: Each column has a sum equal to zero. The column space of such a matrix cannot span all of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Each vector has the property in the column space that its entries sum to zero. This is not true for all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Every basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ has size n. So since the column space does not equal$R^4$ it forms a basis $\leq$3 as if it were $\leq4$ then all the vectors would be linearly independent. Hence its column rank is $<4$ so $\leq3$. So the rank $\leq3$ and since bijectiveness is required the rank has to be 4 which it is not hence the matrix is not invertible?

Comment: 4 linearly independent vectors would imply in this case a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ as there would be a leading one in each column and no zero rows.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be that matrix. The column space of $A$ is the span $\langle A\rangle$ of the columns of $A$. But the sum of the entries of each column is $0$. Therefore, since $\langle A\rangle$ is the space of all linear combinations of vectors such the sum of all of its coordinates is $0$, then *every* element of $\langle A\rangle$ has that property too. So, for instance, $(1,1,1,1)\not\in\langle A\rangle$.